# Unable to understand OGNL expression with in operator

Tags: struts2, ognl

In the official docs:
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/language-guide.html

there is an explanation for `in` operator:
*The in operator (and not in, its negation). This is a containment test, to see if a value is in a collection. For example,*
`name in {null,"Untitled"} || name`

I'm unable to understand this expression but quite intrigued by it.
It checks whether `name` is `null` or `"Untitled"`. If it's not then it returns `name` instead of a boolean value, am I right?

Comment: Why not just try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior of this OGNL expression is weird.
It returns `true` if `name` is either null or `"Untitled"` otherwise it returns the value of `name` if used in a property tag. If used in a if tag then it evaluates to `true` only if the values of `name` are either `null` or `"Untitled"`.
But I wonder what may be a use of such an expression?